# QUICKEST way to find a key in a dictionary

Tags: python, performance, loops, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary, with over 11 million keys (and each value is a list).Each key is a unique integer.

e.g.

```
Dict1 = {11:"a",12:"b",22:"c",56:"d"}
```

Then, separately, I have a list of ranges, e.g.
[10-20,30-40,50-60]

And I want to say, for each range in my list of ranges, go through the dictionary and return the value, if the key is within the range.

So it would return:

```
10-20: "a","b"

50-60: "d"
```

The actual code that I used is:

```
 for each_key in sorted(dictionary):
                if each_key in range(start,end):
                    print str(dictionary[each_key])
```

The problem is that this technique is prohibitively long because it's going through all 11 million keys and checking if it's within the range or not.

Is there a way that I can say "skip through all of the dictionary keys until one in found that is higher than the start number" and then "stop once the end number is higher than the key"? Just basically some way that just zooms in on the portion of the dictionary within a certain range very quickly?

Thanks

Comment: `sorted(dictionary)`, that is doing nothing, as dictionary are unordered

Comment: @AhsanulHaque Actually that will returned a sorted list of the keys in the dictionary. Which could be useful for finding the relevant range except that it's not taken advantage of.

Answer (score 2):

Just use Python's EAFP principle. It's Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission.

Assume that all keys are valid, and catch the error if they're not:

```
for key in xrange(start, end):
    try:
        print str(dictionary[key])
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

This will just try to get each number as a key, and if there's a `KeyError` from a non existent key then it will move on to the next iteration.

Note that if you expect a lot of the keys will be missing, it might be faster to test first:

```
for key in xrange(start, end):
    if key in dictionary:
        print str(dictionary[key])
```

Note that `xrange` is just a slightly different function to `range`. It will produce the values one by one instead of creating the whole list in advance. It's useful to use in for loops and has no drawbacks in this case.

Comment: To me terribly inefficient. what if range is `1-1000000` and only `200` is exist?

Comment: In theory that would be a problem but the OP has the opposite problem, many many keys and trying to access a small number. This method removes their overly expensive loop and sort over all their keys, and instead is based on the small 10 number ranges they need to check.

Comment: If the range is so big, xrange instead of range will have a much better performance

Comment: @Hadrián the dictionary is large, the range isn't. Though there's no reason to not use xrange here, so I'll edit that in

Answer (score 0):

my thought for this problem is to find the correct keys first. The reason why your solution take too much time is that it use O(n) algorithm to find a correct key. If we can implement binary search method, the complexity will be reduced to O(log(n)), which helps a lot.

Following is my sample code. It works for the example, but I cannot promise it won't get some small bugs. Just find the idea there and implement yours.

```
def binarySearch(alist, target):
    left = 0
    right = len(alist) -1

    if target>alist[-1]:
        return len(alist)

    while left < right:
        m = (left + right) / 2 
        if alist[m] == target:
            return m
        if alist[m] < target:
            left = m+1
        else:
            right = m
    return left



def work(dictionary, start, end):
    keys = sorted(dictionary.keys())

    start_pos = binarySearch(keys, start)
    end_pos = binarySearch(keys, end)


    print [dictionary[keys[pos]] for pos in range(start_pos,end_pos)] 


dictionary = {11:"a",12:"b",22:"c",56:"d"}
work(dictionary, 10, 20)
work(dictionary, 20, 40)
work(dictionary, 10, 60)
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution ( using OrderedDict and filter ) can help you a bit.

```
from collections  import OrderedDict
d = {2:3, 10:89, 4:5, 23:0}
od = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))

lst=["1-10","11-20","21-30"]
lower_lst=map(int,[i.split("-")[0] for i in lst])
upper_lst=map(int,[i.split("-")[1] for i in lst])

for low,up in zip(lower_lst,upper_lst):
    print "In range {0}-{1}".format(low,up),filter(lambda a:low <= a[0] <= up,od.iteritems())
```

Comment: Wouldn't it take a very long time sorting and creating an `OrderedDict` with 11 million keys? I feel like the OP's initial sort is part of their time problem.